# Infinite cyclic cover corresponding to non-zero cohomology class $\alpha \in H^1(x,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, covering-spaces

I want to understand the following sentence:

> Let X a compact (complex) manifold which has a non-zero cohomology class $\alpha \in H^1(X,\mathbb Z)$. Let $\pi: \bar X\to X$ be the corresponding infinite cyclic covering.

What does this mean? It seems that an infinite cyclic covering is a cover with fiber $\mathbb Z$.
But why does such a covering exist, and how is it related to the cohomology class?

Comment: $H^1(X;G) = \text{Hom}(\pi_1, G)$.

Comment: Your hypothetical Stiefel-Whitney class would live in   $ H^1(X,\mathbb Z/2)$, not in $ H^1(X,\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg One more reason why this seems to be the wrong approach. I guess I can delete that part.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Any ideas how to proceed from here? The only thing I could think of was that $\alpha: \pi_1(X) \to \mathbb Z = \pi_1(K(\mathbb Z,1))$ and so $\alpha$ is induced by a map from $X\to K(\mathbb Z,1)=S^1$. But this is not the map I look for.

Comment: What is a covering space of a connected space with fiber $G$ but a homomorphism $\pi_1X \to G$? (And in any case, that certainly is "the map you're looking for", whatever you mean by that; I'm not sure what.)

Comment: @klirk It's standard covering space theory that homomorphisms $\pi_1(X) \to \Bbb Z$ classify infinite cyclic covers. Do you know covering space theory? If not, look at Hatcher chapter 1.3.

Comment: @MikeMiller Isn't a covering space a homomorphism $\pi_1 X \to \text{Sym}(G)$?

Comment: It seems the definition I used was wrong, infinite cyclic cover means that the group of deck transformation of the cover is infinite cyclic.

Comment: I assumed "fiber $\Bbb Z$" meant that you came equipped with an isomorphism $\text{Deck}(\bar X,X) \cong \Bbb Z$ which acts transitively on fibers. That's what is meant here. (This is how I would interpret "fiber $G$" for $G$ a group.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way this works is that in the universal coefficient theorem,
$$0\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(H_0(X),\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_1(X),\mathbb{Z}) \to 0,$$
the $\operatorname{Ext}$ group is trivial, so the cohomology is isomorphic to the group of homomorphisms $H_1(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$.  By the Hurewicz theorem, this is isomorphic to the group of homomorphisms $\pi_1(X)\to\mathbb{Z}$ since $H_1(X)$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1(X)$.  One could also use $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})=[X,K(\mathbb{Z},1)]=\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{Z})$.

Given a map $f:\pi_1(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$, there is a normal covering space corresponding to $\ker f$.  The infinite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$ is the group of deck transformations of this covering space, and so it is called an *infinite cyclic cover*.

(For non-normal covers, say  for a subgroup $G\subset \pi_1(X)$, there is a map $\pi_1(X)\to \operatorname{Sym}(\pi_1(X)/G)$ of permutations of the fiber, where cosets of $G$ are in one-to-one correspondence with points of that fiber.  If $G$ is a normal subgroup then the image of this map has a group structure.)

Concretely, given $\alpha\in H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$, the corresponding homomorphism $f:\pi_1(X)\to\mathbb{Z}$ "integrates $\alpha$ along a path."  This function measures how many sheets up or down one travels in the infinite cyclic cover when walking along that path.

Since $X$ is a compact complex manifold, it is orientable.  Thus, Poincare-Lefschetz duality applies and gives $H^1(M)\cong H_{n-1}(M,\partial M)$.  In certain situations, the corresponding homology class to $\alpha$ might be an embedded $(n-1)$-manifold (for example $n=2$, or if $X$ is merely orientable but not complex, $n=3$).  One can produce an infinite cyclic cover by cutting $X$ along this submanifold, which should be thought of as doing a branch cut, then taking one copy of this for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and finally gluing the $n$th copy to the $(n+1)$th copy along the cut for all $n$.